# How to intercept and process incoming emails on server?

Tags: .net, email

I need to implement an Email To Message solution like Basecamp is using.
I have searched and found some suggestions like sending a unique id in subject or body of email and then reading mailbox and filtering emails by this unique id. It works but client want its exactly like BaseCamp.

So please suggest from where i could start or is there any third party .Net component which i can use.

A Third party component which can intercept incoming Emails on server before Pop3 or IMAP and save them in custom database.

Email doesn't required to go into mailbox I just want it to add in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution while googling a lot.

There is a website www.mailgun.com which provides same features which i need.

I have tested their services and its working according to my needs.

Thanks